# Degree and genus of projected curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, genus

Let $C\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ be a normal curve over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$. Assume that $C$ is not contained in any hyperplane. We may assume that $P=[0:\cdots:0:1]$ is on $C$. Consider the projection $\pi:\mathbb{P}^n\dashrightarrow\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ away from $P$ i.e. $[x_0:\cdots:x_{n-1}:x_n]\mapsto[x_0:\cdots:x_{n-1}]$. Let $C'=\pi(C)$. What can we say about the degree and genus of $C'$?

In Fisher's [The higher secant varieties of an elliptic normal curve](http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Etaf1000/papers/hsecenc.pdf) Lemma 5.2, it was stated for elliptic curves but without proof. Do we have similar conclusions for higher genera?

Comment: It seems to me that you should have a look to the well-known Riemann-Hurwitz formula e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Hurwitz_formula

Comment: I assume that the induced map $C\rightarrow C'$ has degree one. If $P$ is a smooth point, the degree of $C'$ is just $\deg(C)-1$ (in general, $\deg(C)-m(P)$). Of course the geometric genus is the same; for the arithmetic genus we have $g(C')\geq g(C)$, the difference depending on possible trisecants to $C$ passing through $P$.

Comment: @abx P is smooth since the OP assumed the curve to be normal, isn't it?

Comment: @Holonomia: Probably right. I am not sure if "normal" means smooth or projectively normal.

Comment: @abx Yes. The word "normal" means smooth. But why can we say that the degree is $1$? Or is there a hyperplane such that the induced projection has degree $1$?

Comment: I wrote $\deg (C')=\deg(C)-1$ — an easy exercise.

Comment: @abx I think this holds only with the assumption that the map $C\to C'$ has degree $1$. My question is why we can assume that.

Comment: @Li Li   I guess abx assumed the map has degree 1 just to give you an example, actually it is the generic case. But you can construct projections of higher degree e.g. take a cylinder over a plane curve a cut it with a small deformation of  $d$  parallel planes.

Comment: @Holonomia Thanks for your explanation. How should I understand your saying "generic case"? Does this mean that for a general point and a hyperplane, the induced projection has degree $1$? How can I see this?

Comment: by generic I had in mind projection from any point of any curve

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: you can also fix the curve an project from a generic point, but you should avoid the strange curves see Hartshorne’s book (search for strange curve)